# React native image crop

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, crop

I'm trying to add image crop functionality to my React-native app. I've already tried
`react-native-image-crop-picker`.

While this has been useful I can't seem to customize the crop screen. I need to change the UI completely. Is there another option to cropping images in react-native. All the links suggest the same package.

Comment: You can try these options: https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-react-native, https://github.com/callstack/react-native-image-editor

Comment: @DánielBoros I will try them. Thank you.

Comment: @DánielBoros The first pkg is a bit heavy since I only need the crop feature. And the second I'm not sure if it opens the crop feature in a new screen vs doing it simply with coordinates